# API's are giving Network Error with https url in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, axios

backend api's are giving **Network Error** with https url, when we change https to http, it starts responding.

React-native-version: 0.63
axios version: 0.18.0

Comment: Seems like either the SSL certificate is wrong or the server does not support SSL (port 443). Could you please paste all of the response error? Also, is the request you do a cross-domain one?

Comment: how to add SSL certificate in react-native?

Comment: This is not about react-native, but about the backend itself. Can you access the API endpoints via https in the browser?

Comment: @t1gor yep, we are able to access apis with https from browser